# psycopg2 - how to detect broken but not closed connection?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm using psycopg2 ThreadedConnectionPool.

When putting an already closed connection back in the pool using [psycopg2's `putconn`](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/blob/master/lib/pool.py), it doesn't get added to the pool, assuring that I won't be getting a closed connection next time I call `get_conn`.

Is there a case in which the connection is broken (as in not usable anymore) but not closed?

If so, how can I detect it?

For example:

```py
from psycopg2.pool import ThreadedConnectionPool

DSN = "postgresql://User:password@localhost/db"
pool = ThreadedConnectionPool(8, 10, DSN)

def execute(query):
    close = False
    conn = pool.getconn()
    try:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(query)
        cur.commit()
    except ExceptionThatIndicatesTheConnectionIsBrokenButNotClosed:
        close = True
    except Exception:
        conn.rollback()
    pool.putconn(conn, close=close)
```

`ExceptionThatIndicatesTheConnectionIsBrokenButNotClosed` - are there any specific exceptions/pgcodes/pgerros that indicate just that?

Thanks :)